# How to select rows that begin with any word found in list?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sql-like

I have a table called Assets and each row has a column called Category. Some category names can look like the following...

```
Fruit
Fruit-Apple
Fruit-Orange
Vegetable
Vegetable-Carrot
Vegetable-Lettuce
Dairy-Cheese
Dairy-Milk
```

How can I select all rows that start with ('Fruit', or 'Dairy')? I would normally use the **Like** but i do not know how to use that when filtering with a list of possible patterns?

I would expect my query results to be this:

```
Fruit
Fruit-Apple
Fruit-Orange
Dairy-Cheese
Dairy-Milk
```

This SELECT only works for complete category value match

```
SELECT tags FROM Assets WHERE category in ('Fruit','Dairy') AND tags is not ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `or`:

```
where category like 'Fruit%' or category like 'Dairy%'
```

SQLite has extensions to support regular expressions.  If you are using that:

```
where category regexp '^(Fruit|Dairy)'
```

Comment: I was hoping your regex method would work but it didn't

Answer (score 1):

With a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) containing all the category prefixes that you want to compare the categories in the table:

```
with cte(category) as (values ('Fruit'), ('Dairy'))  
select a.category
from assets a inner join cte c
on a.category like c.category || '%'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9gCPCrXVS2uF51sJndh59e/2).
If you want to use regular expression you can do it with [`GLOB`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

```
select *
from assets  
where category glob '[Fruit,Dairy]*'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9gCPCrXVS2uF51sJndh59e/4).
Results:

```
| category     |
| ------------ |
| Fruit        |
| Fruit-Apple  |
| Fruit-Orange |
| Dairy-Cheese |
| Dairy-Milk   |
```